# Ruby overriding method from Trie gem - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trie

I use Trie (https://github.com/tyler/trie) gem in project and love it. But it has one issue that is really anoying.

`has_key?` method returns `nil` when key is not found instead of `false` (as every method ending with `?` should)

I've tried opening an issue on their GitHub (https://github.com/tyler/trie/issues/26) but no luck.

So, reasonable next step - try to override the method.

I added this to my project:

```
class Trie
    alias :old_has_key? :has_key?
    def has_key?(key)
        puts "My new Trie has_key"
        old_has_key?(key)
    end
end
```

Just to see if I can get away with it.

Unfortunately, when I run `rails console` I get:

```
`<class:Trie>': undefined method `has_key?' for class `Trie' (NameError)
```

As I found elsewhere, this should work. Any idea why it doesn't?

What I'm missing here? Location of `trie.rb`? Something else?

Comment: The most commonly accepted definition of predicate methods (like `has_key?`) is that it returns a truthy or falsey value. Returning `nil` as a falsey value works just fine here most of the time. If you use it in a condition like `if trie.has_key?('whatever')` it works just the same as if `false` would have ben returned.

Comment: The most obvious example is the `defined?` operator (technically not a method, though) which returns `nil` for undefined and a string describing the definition otherwise.

Comment: Ok, what is right is arguable, but even their docs are wrong because they say that method returns `true/false` which it doesn't.

I know that it works in most cases, but it doesn't work when you are trying to compare it with some other boolean value.

My question still remains, why I get that error, that's what's puzzling me.

Comment: The docs do indeed not fully reflect the reality. However, the code as it stands today should still be quite usable. If you really need either true ir false, you can just use `result = !!my_trie.has_key?('whatever')`.

Comment: If you want to use boolean logic with a ruby object, just use the object directly instead of comparing to `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

From your error message, it seems you are calling the `has_key?` method on the `Trie` class, not an instance of it. If you create an instance, your code works just fine:

```
my_trie = Trie.new
my_trie.has_key?('foo')
# My new Trie has_key
# => nil
```

Comment: Actually I get error when I try to run `rails console`. Call doesn't even get executed. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Again, your code works, as long as you use it correctly. Check the strack trace of your error. Probably, there is some call to `Trie.has_key?('whatever')` which is executed during startup of rails and which results in the error.

Comment: It turns out that I had to move my `trie.rb` deeper into hierarchy. Not quite sure why.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem.

My new class was nested under `/lib` folder in my Rails app. As soon as I moved it to `/lib/utils/` it worked!

This means that loader picked up my custom class before actual `Trie` class. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch a little more simply:

```
class Trie
    def has_key?(key)
       !!super
    end
end
```